# What is 8 pin tssop packed component?232/485 ethernet converter

Tags: components, rs232, rs485

[image]
-size =    2.9mmx3.1mm
-GND pin = 1,6,7 connected
-7.pin 4.7uh connected

Comment: 8-pin IC with a 4.7uH inductor screams switch-mode power supply to me. 
But cmon - you couldn't even tell us the part markings or add a photo?

Comment: can you look at the picture

Comment: Yep - with that large inductor and the PCB layout it's definitely a switcher.

Comment: Can we find datasheet?

Comment: My first thought would be that it's an ST L6928, but the pinout doesn't seem to match...

Comment: yes i looked at it now looks at the 6 pin vcc L6928

Comment: This may help you narrow it down further: Pin 8 looks to be the supply for the chip (judging by the bypass caps and multiple vias). I agree it's certainly a switcher. If you can measure the voltage on the node connecting L2 to C11 and C14, that should be the output of the switcher and would help narrow down your search.

Comment: your question says "GND pin = 1,6,7 connected" - is this a typo? 7 does not look like it's connected to GND.

Comment: Yes , 7 connected to 4.7 uh .

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a [L6928D013TR](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/stmicroelectronics/L6928D013TR/497-4222-1-ND/725513)

Per the [Datasheet](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/9f/84/07/dd/b0/3f/4d/f9/CD00047477.pdf/files/CD00047477.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00047477.pdf) your pin out looks right too. Other than you say 7 to the 4.7uH and I think you mean 5 as you already have 7 connected to 1 and 6.

[image]

I also found an eval board for the chip and if you look at the chip markings they are a match. Second line for YWW is obviously different.
[image]

Comment: From the layout image it's pretty clear pin 7 of U2 is connected to L2, not pin 5.

Comment: Yeah - the chip marking matches the first line, but how do you explain the OP's PCB having a very different pinout? I don't see an option in the datasheet for a different version of the part.

Comment: I don't see how they have it either, however there are a couple different circuits in the app notes that work slightly different. Again i can't narrow it down. https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/73/d9/c5/8c/47/18/4d/75/CD00049152.pdf/files/CD00049152.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00049152.pdf I still suspect it is the right chip being right package, right markings, similar circuit. Though I will be the first to admit I am not perfect. I have also see circuit designers change the design of a circuit from the MFG example. Would be nice to have in hand